# Resources on preventing MVVM from over firing commands and properties

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I am wondering if anyone has any good resources on developing and architecting MVVM specifically to ensure that properties and commands are not firing more often then they need to be.

I'm working on a very large MVVM enterprise application, and a big problem that we are running into is that some commands and properties are being hit 5 or 6 times throughout the course of execution.  This is way too much.  In a MVC patter, we'd only have these being hit once each as needed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to look for resources to prevent this?

Comment: I don't understand, why are they being hit? In MVVM we too get hit once each is needed. Do you have some code, or some specific case we can look? I've dealt with large applications, but haven't seen this.

Comment: It sounds like memory leaks... Does the number of calls increases with each new opening view?

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but are you using `RelayCommands` or `DelegateCommands`? A `RelayCommand` will typically re-query it's `CanExecute` anytime *any* property raises a change notification, while a `DelegateCommand` usually needs to be specifically told when it should raise its `CanExecute`